# Hosting Django Rest framework on its own server

Tags: django, apache, django-rest-framework, ubuntu-18.04

So I have an angular front end with an Django rest framework backend that's hosted on a single ubuntu 18.04 VPS box running apache. The front end is hosted on port 80 and the backend is at port 8000 and we noticed it seems like a lot of networks block port 8000. So what happens is if I logon on a public wifi you can see the front end but you can't access the backend.

I need some guidance on how to make this work. Right now it's setup like so

```
Api requests are: http://myapp.com:8000
In the future all API quests should be: http://myapp.com/api
or maybe even a separate server that's http://api.myapp.com
```

I'm asking for some guidance on this issue. Is there anyway to just make apache think that all requests are on port 80/443 and i don't need the 8000 anymore? and for a small app is that an okay practice? OR should I just run the backend on a separate server and if so how do I set that up? all guides seem to point to putting that on 8000. Any links and guidance on this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you logon to public wifi and there is a policy on the network to block traffic reaching out to a server's port 80, the requests will probably just time out.

If you NEED to serve the app separately and can't serve it via Django, using Virutal Hosts and configuring appropriate rules may be best ([see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/231295/hosting-two-web-applications-on-same-server)). Using this, you might have app.domain.com serve any requests for application files and api.domain.com route requsts to your django backend. Depending on how you set up the rules, you might need a custom CORS policy (as api.domain.com and app.django.com are two distinct domain names).